# Java regexp OR is too slow

Tags: java, regex, performance

Why pattern

```
[0123]123456|98765
```

is twice slow as execute **[0123]123456** and then **98765** in Java? So it's faster to search them separately than execute with OR. Does anybody have explanation?

**UPD**

See for test example with results:
https://gist.github.com/cy6erGn0m/5077720

**UPD2**

I discovered the reason is inside java.util.regex. The following test makes it clear: https://gist.github.com/cy6erGn0m/5083426

So as you can see Matcher make significantly more requests to source char sequence. So the first pattern requires about 2x times more requests to source than two separate patterns.

Multiline and case insensitive is irrelevant. Or operator affects complexity.

Comment: Is that your exact pattern? How are you testing it?

Comment: With the use case of searching for match in the string, there is indeed difference (it is not twice as slow on my computer, though). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5076963 On ideone: http://ideone.com/447pPO

Comment: My test is looks like provided by nhahtdh. My results shows that first pattern is about 2-3x slower. In my own test average times: 2700ms vs 950ms

Comment: Your comparison may be unfair. You compile the pattern with the alternation using the `MULTILINE` and `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flags; you're not doing that with the second pattern in the `OR` test. I'm not sure how that affects performance - can you try it out?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I replace my own `generateInput` (random string, with length from 10 - 90 characters) with his way of generating input (one string at ~34 mil characters, I reduce his loop from 14M to 5M). For such input, the difference on my system is 2 times.

Comment: Options will affect performance but difference between these patterns will be the same.

Comment: Also I'am sure my comparison is fair because this test running long time: about 300 seconds and as you can see in log the results are very stable.

Comment: For comparison, it might be interesting to do matching with `indexOf("98765")` and `int i=indexOf("123456"); i>0 && "0123".contains(str.charAt(i-1));` style custom matcher...

Comment: Your pattern is incorrect. `[0123]123456|98765` is equivalent to `[0123]12345(6|9)8765`, not `[0123](123456|98765)`.

Comment: Not sure whether that would affect the speed, though, unless longer pattern options always take longer to match.

Comment: Particular example is not affect anything. You may use any pattern with OR. My pattern is just example. So it's correct since it reproduces the issue and there is no difference what it actually matches.

About pattern length. Of course the longer pattern is slower. But sum of lengths of it's parts is the same. So why should it be faster? This is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. It looks like I found one half of the answer.

When we have only pattern like 123456 then regexp engine uses Boyer-Moore string matching algorithm. But if you have OR then it don't use it and simply compares every character.

Due to it's nature Boyer-Moore algorythm may be much more efficient so this is why second approach is faster.

For example if I have input string "11223344" and pattern "123456" then according to Boyer-Moore implementation the only character should be checked is '3' at 5th position. This is much more efficient than try to test pattern against EVERY character.